# Definition of equality amongst elements of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we are given an arbitrary vector space $V(\mathbb{F})$. We define by a set of axioms what are the properties that a given vector space has to in the form of binary operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication for it to be considered as a vector space.

However, we do not strictly define what is equality in the context of vectors.

Different vector spaces have different definitions of equality. For eg. the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n(\mathbb R)$ considering elements as n-tuples we call two vectors equal iff they are component-wise equal. Similarly, we define equality on the vector space $P_n(\mathbb R)$ i.e. the set of polynomials with degree $\le n$, as equality of coefficients. While for $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$ it is defined as element-wise equality.

So I wanted to ask that is it not necessary to define equality of vectors beforehand and bind it as a set of axioms just like scalar multiplication or vector addition as the definition of equality is unique to a vector space based on the structure it defines. In a more fundamental sense, what do I mean when I say that $u+v=v+u$ when I have not even defined what equality to that specific vector space means.

Comment: Usually, a vector space is a set with extra structure. We get the notion of equality from the set, since sets have a notion of equality (of elements).

Comment: I was trying to derive the properties of a vector space in a sequential manner. So, logically I cannot use basis to define equality as the former has itself been derived after a vector space was defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a really good question! So, what you're talking about is an example of a **first-order theory with equality**. We define the axioms for equality beforehand (I'll state them in a minute), and then add a set of proper symbols $\mathcal P$ and proper axioms. Other examples of first-order theories with equality include that of groups, abelian groups, lattices, posets, etc.

> **Axioms for Equality:**
>
> 1. $\forall x (x=x)$
> 2. $\forall x_1...\forall x_n\forall y_1...\forall y_n ((x_1=y_1 \land ...\land x_n=y_n)\to (p^nx_1...x_n \leftrightarrow p^ny_1...y_n))$ for each n-ary predicate symbol $p^n$ in the first order language.
> 3. $\forall x_1...\forall x_n\forall y_1...\forall y_n ((x_1=y_1 \land ...\land x_n=y_n)\to (f^nx_1...x_n = f^ny_1...y_n))$ for each n-ary function symbol $f^n$ in the first order language.

Now, we add to the above axioms a set of **proper axioms and proper symbols** to describe what is known as a vector space:

> **Proper symbols, functions, relations:**
>
> 1. There is an element $0\in V$, called zero.
> 2. A function symbol $\alpha: V\times V\to V$, written as $\alpha(v,w) = v+w$.
> 3. Another function symbol $\mu: \mathbb F\times V\to V$, written as $\mu(\lambda,v) = \lambda\cdot v$.

You may be wondering why I'm calling this a **first-order theory**. The following proper axioms will make that evident:

> **Vector Space (Proper) Axioms:**
>
> 1. $\forall x\forall y (x+y = y+x)$
> 2. $\forall x\forall y\forall z (x+(y+z) = (x+y)+z)$
> 3. $\forall x(0+x = x)$
> 4. $\forall x\exists y (x+y = 0)$
> 5. $\forall x(1\cdot x = x)$
> 6. $\forall a\forall b \forall x((ab)\cdot x = a\cdot (b\cdot x))$
> 7. $\forall a\forall x\forall y (a\cdot(x+y) = a\cdot x + a\cdot y)$
> 8. $\forall a\forall b\forall x ((a+b)\cdot x = a\cdot x + b\cdot x)$

Whenever I say $\forall x, \forall y, \exists y$ I really mean $\forall x\in V, \forall y\in V, \exists y\in V$ respectively. Whenever I say $\forall a,\forall b$ I really mean $\forall a\in\mathbb F,\forall b\in\mathbb F$, respectively.

Clearly, all the axioms of vector spaces are expressible in terms of the first-order language (note the quantifiers, $\forall,\exists$) endowed with the special symbol of equality (and its axioms). Hence, this is a first-order theory with equality. I hope this helps. Please let me know if you've any questions!

---

*To summarize:* We don't worry about defining $=$ among the vector space axioms, because **the intention is to complement the vector space axioms with the equality axioms** - and their amalgamation is the *first-order theory (with equality) of vector spaces.*

Comment: Also the syntactic equality in this case is always modelled  with the "diagonal" relation $\{(a,a):a\in M\}$, where $M$ is a model of the theory.

Comment: @Koncopd Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't what you're saying obviously equivalent to the first axiom of equality as stated in my answer, i.e. $\forall (x=x)$?

Comment: Any equivalence relation has this, not only the diagonal one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic)#Interpreting_equality maybe i am not right that this is always the case, but in linear algebra and functional analysis normal models are used almost always,  this is the reason why the quotient spaces are formed instead of interpreting the equality symbol with a corresponding equivalence relation.

Answer (score 2):

The easy variant is to take equality as identity and as integral parto of logic (First Order Logic with Equality). In effect $a=b$ is true whenever $\phi(a)\leftrightarrow\phi(b)$ for every logical predicate $\phi$.

Comment: I had been thinking about this for a while if it is possible to define a map $V\times V\rightarrow [0,1]$ i.e. defining equality as a binary operation mapping to a boolean set